# Inverse Laplace Transform Mixing Sine and Exponential

Tags: laplace-transform

I have a doubt about Laplace transforms. Most concretely, about the existence of an inverse.

I know already these facts

$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}(\exp(-\sqrt{s}))=\frac{\exp({-\frac{1}{4 t}})}{2 \sqrt{\pi } t^{3/2}}.$$
$$\mathcal{L}(\sin(-\sqrt{s})) \text{ does not exist}.$$

I was wondering if $$\mathcal{L}^{-1}(\exp(-\sqrt{s}) \cdot \sin(-\sqrt{s}))$$ exists or not. I know that if $\mathcal{L}(\sin(-\sqrt{s}))$ existed, then I could apply Convolution Theorem to get the result. But this is not the case, so I am not even sure about the existence.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If the ILT of one of the transforms does not exist, what makes you think a convolution involving one of those transforms exists?

Comment: I think it just can be possible, I am not saying it does exist or it does not. For instance, a tautological example happens if you change the $\exp(-\sqrt{s})$ by $\frac{1}{\sin(-\sqrt{s})} \cdot f(s)$ where $f$ is any function that you know it's ILT...